# How to use Azure cognitive service SDK in node.js context

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I want to use Azure cognitive services SDK with Websockets, not in a web context, but in node.js context, how to solve this, without using Chrome Headless ?

Comment: This question doesn't offer enough information.  Most of the Cognitive Services are REST-based.  What specifically do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have node.js SDK. However please use the published protocol to write your own until we publish more SDKs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol